# how is original value from immutable variable accessed?

Tags: java, python, data-structures, data-persistence, immutablelist

Immutable variable: a type of variable that stores it's original version if it is modified.
Question: how do I access the older version of that variable in Python? or in Java? or any other languages that support this "persistent data structure?" 
or am I wrong about the definition of Immutable variables?

After I change a variable in, let's say ,**python**:

```
name = "nice name"
name = "bad name"
```

now, how do I retrieve the older value of `var name`?

**Note**: This question is different from the one it has been marked as duplicate of because, this question is about the **memory location of variables** and the other question is about the **scope of variables**.

Comment: Hope this link http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/immutable.htm helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `name` is a reference that points to a value.

In your first line, `name` points to the immutable string "nice name".

Then in your second line, you update `name` to point to a different immutable string "bad name".

At this point, no variable references "nice name" - so it is no longer available.

The `str` type is immutable because the "nice name" value itself cannot be updated. Any operation on a string will create a new block of memory to store the modified string in.  In your example, "nice name" and "bad name" are stored in different blocks of memory - all that you are updating is the reference to the memory block.

Comment: so, the only way to keep that value is to give the old pointer to another variable?

Comment: If so, what is the significance of that "**previous block of memory**"?

Comment: If you have a variable pointing to the memory, then you can still access it.  But once you have no variable pointing to the memory, the memory is considered unreferenced and will be [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) i.e. cleared without you needing to explicitly ask for it.

Comment: thank you! that helps, I have one last question, is this persistent data structure a designed feature of programming languages? or is it a limitation? i mean "defect"?

Comment: It depends on your point of view. To a functional programmer, immutable variables and persistent data structures are normal, and mutation is a "defect." Imperative and object-oriented programmers disagree. But I can't explain that in a 600-character comment, or even in a full StackOverflow answer. You should read a few books about functional programming before you decide that immutable variables are a "defect."